# Can I run Connectify in a virtual Machine running windows 7 on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, vmware-fusion, hotspot

I have MBP 13' and I tested the Connectify on bootcamp. It works fine, but the problem is that I need Connectify to run on my Mac too. On my current Wifi network I can connect to the internet using one device at a time and I have a few other devices. So I'm asking, is there anyway or any software that could configure Mac OSX to act as an Access Point like Connectify on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this tutorial.](http://psp.mmgn.com/Articles/Using-an-Apple-Mac-as-a-Wirele-F) It uses built in OS X settings to create an access point.

> This was done on the latest version of
>   Mac OSX, Leopard (10.5), using a 2007
>   Macbook Pro

They also listed the downsides to doing it this way

```
You can’t use the wireless adapter for anything else while its being shared.
For Macbook's it will drain the battery so ensure its plugged into a power source
If Mac crashes so does your online Gaming.
Potentially could expose your Computer to outside attack…… (I have to put it for legal reasons I guess!)
Have to have a Mac for it to work (C’mon that’s not a Con….. That’s a Positive!!!!)
If using it for a PSP or a PS3 you need to run the Wireless Network Unprotected.
```